# Flex 3 why does update complete event 2 times

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Flex 3 why does the update complete event come 2 times. It is the best event for me to recognize if the component is ready to be used. Variables set, bindings, everything... But it comes twice, I wonder if that is always the case and why.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` is dispatched on every update of the display list. It is dispatched after every invalidation - after user interaction or change in the components on the current display list. Use `FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` instead. It is dispatched only once (initiated by the `LayoutManager`), just after the component has been initialized and added to the display list.

There are many articles about the Flex component lifecycle (e.g. [this](https://flexcomps.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/flex-component-life-cycle/)), where you can find more information about the invalidation mechanisms and the events dispatched.

Comment: _Thanks for the explanation. Hope all this process of invalidation, commit and the lifecycle of the components get's simpler on the new sdk. Thanks again!_

Comment: The invalidation mechanism is a core concept in Flex. Its goal is to reduce the amount of work which the SDK does. Another benefit is that it reduces the sequential coupling of the UI components. Probably it won't get simpler in the new versions of Flex. :-)